# Send data from plugin to external database

Tags: php, plugin-development, mysql

I'm creating a plugin that I need write data to an external database (not the wp db that the plugin is on). I know I can use `require_once` with a separate config file with the external db details in that. However, if this is to be a publicly available plugin, wouldn't that mean that anyone who has the plugin would be able to see the db username and password?

Has anyone got any ideas of how to do this securely?

Comment: You should be using an API on your server - you POST data to it, and your server actually handles storing in the database.

Comment: Is an API the only way to do it? I've never had to do anything like this before, can you point me towards a tutorial?

Comment: At its most basic it'll just be a script on your server that handles the request (e.g. `$_POST`), perhaps returns errors/messages, and then ultimately stores it in the db. I don't think you'll find an "API tutorial" other than what I've described because an API itself is nothing, it's just a term for creating a "bridge" between two services; in your case, all the sites that have your plugin installed, and the database on your server.

Comment: Ah ok, the only experience I've had with APIs so far has been JSON and GET. So am I right in guessing that I can $_POST from the plugin and then use $_GET on my side?